# How to install man page for "perf" tool on RHEL?

Tags: linux, installation, yum, perf, manpage

I'm running rhel 5.7 and found there's no man page for "perf". How can I install one, any package name or yum name contains "perf"?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://serverfault.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think perf is available from RHEL 6 on. Did you mean to say you were using RHEL 6.7 ?
Your RHEL 5.7 is a critically old and probably has several critical security issues and vulnerabilities. Also all production support on RHEL 5 systems ceases 31/03/2017 which is pretty close !
See  https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata for more detail

If you are actually using RHEL 6.7 it should be easy to install perf with yum:

```
yum install perf
```

provided you have set up the repositories or have the install media handy.